# JSLint It is not necessary to initialize undefined

Tags: javascript, jslint

While validating my JavaScript code in JSLint (www.jslint.com). I got a error I've never seen before. Is this something new ?

It tells me that:

It is not necessary to initialize 'i' to 'undefined'. On this:

```
var i = 0,
    l = data.d.ResponseData.length,
    x;
```

Does anyone know what this means?

..fredrik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a bug introduced in the most recent update. It has since [been fixed](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jslint_com/message/1060).

Comment: Ah, googled it before my post here. Tested it didn't work. Then I remembered that it's a client side application. Clear cache. Works! Thanks!